# In JAGS, how does the stochastic node works?

Tags: r, statistics, modeling, bayesian, jags

...and what does the ~ sign mean compared to R in y[I] ~ dnorm(m[i],tau) vs y[I] <- dnorm(n,m[i],tau)?

Consider the two lines of code:

```
`for(I in 1:length(y)) {
y[i] ~ dnorm(m[i],tau)  #---> Jags code (stochastic node)
m[i] = alpha + beta*(x[i] - x_bar)
.
.
}
y[i] <- dnorm(n,m[i],tau)?) ---> R`
```

In Jags, what will be the n values since it is not specified inside the dnorm function? (dnorm(m[i],tau))

For each i, does the dnorm function calculate the density values for each y value with respect to the mean m[I] which has a linear relationship determined by the deterministic node and tau(precision)?

In short, I wanna know what n values will be used by dnorm or any other density function for distributions(dgamma or dbeta).

Answer (score 0):

In this specific instance `y` is your response variable, `m` is your linear predictor, and `tau` is precision (the inverse of variance). Using `~` makes the relationship stochastic. Looking to the JAGS user manual...

"Relations can be of two types. A stochastic relation (`~`) defines a stochastic node, representing a random variable in the model. A deterministic relation (`<-`) defines a deterministic
node, the value of which is determined exactly by the values of its parents. The equals sign
(`=`) can be used for a deterministic relation in place of the left arrow (`<-`)."

So, in other words, you are assuming that the values in `y` are drawn from a normal distribution that are related to `m` and `tau`.

While `dnorm` in R calculates the density, JAGS calculates the log density (as per the user manual).  Effectively, this stochastic relationship allows you to use `y` and `x` to estimate `alpha`, `beta`, and `tau`, and you use `dnorm` in this case by making a distributional assumption about the data generating process.

Of course, as this is a Bayesian analysis, you'll need priors for your parameters. You can also deterministically calculate the standard deviation instead of precision. A full model would look something like...

```
model{
# likelihood
for(I in 1:length(y)) {
y[i] ~ dnorm(m[i],tau) 
m[i] <- alpha + beta*(x[i] - x_bar)
}
# priors
tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
sd <- 1/ sqrt(tau)
alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
}
```

Comment: Hi mfidino, Thanks for your response. But the core of my question is this -" What is the  value of n that the dnorm function will take to compute the log density in JAGS?" [dnorm(n, u, sig); but in Jags code, the n is not specified. I skimmed through the entire JAGS manual and this question is not answered or is not explicitly answered for a beginner using JAGS]

Comment: The `n` is not specified. Instead, `JAGS` uses the 1:n  (in your example `1:length(y)`) value's in `y` through a loop to estimate the parameters specified in `dnorm` (i.e., alpha, beta, and tau). The `dnorm` functions in `JAGS` and `R` are not the same.

Comment: so if y = [7,5,3,9,4,5], for each iteration from 1:5, the dnorm in bugs will use the y values (for ex y[2] = 5) for n?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is using those data to parameterize your model.